# Pandas does not recognise the same index on concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a for cycle and in each iteration I get a Dataframe which I want to concatenate to an existing one like this:

```
for stock in request.json:
   stock_data = quandl.get('WIKI/{}.11'.format(stock['symbol'].rstrip()), start_date=start, end_date=end)
   stock_data.rename({'Adj. Close': stock['symbol'].rstrip()}, inplace=True, axis=1)
   stocks = pd.concat([stocks, stock_data], axis=1, sort=True)
```

The result is that only the last concatenated column will be ok, the previous ones are filled whit `Nan`. I think the problem is that the `index` which is the `Date` column is not recognized.
I tried searching for my problem but none of the solutions resolved my problem.
How can I concatenate in each iteration?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ignore_index = True` in `pd.concat([stocks, stock_data], axis=1, sort=True, ignore_index=True)`?

Comment: @Tom Yes I tried, same behaviour. Only the column names will be 0, 1 and so on.

Comment: I suggest you to limit stocks number to small amount and inspect on each stage what is the result (yes, print-style debugging).

Comment: At the first row in the for cycle I get the data with the `Date` index, at the second row is the same but the column is renamed to the symbol value, at the third row, if I am in the first iteration everything is good, if not, only the last column is filled up with values, the rest is `Nan`.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert Can you show an example of what `stocks` and `stock_data` look like during one iteration? Even just the `head`?